# How to Fetch Data/Values from the Promise Object in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

What I have is a simple registration page, which registers users and adds the form data into the db. What i want is to show the list of user details, for which i have a register component and a listing service. Here is my register.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserData } from '../userdata';
import { ListingService } from '../listing.service';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

    role : any[];

    data : Promise<any>

    userdata : any[];

    constructor(private listingService : ListingService, private http : Http) { this.role = ["Admin","Super-Admin","User"] }

    selectedRole: Object = {};  

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    registerUser(form: NgForm)
    {
        //console.log(form.value);      
        let details = JSON.stringify(form.value);                       
        this.data = this.listingService.registerUser(details)
        .then((result) => {console.log(result); this.userdata = result;})
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

        alert(this.data);
    }


}
```

Alerting "alert(this.data)" gives me [object Promise], so my question is how to fetch the data from this.data which is a promise object ?

My service is, listing.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
//import { toPromise } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { UserData } from './userdata';

@Injectable()

export class ListingService
{
    headers: Headers;
    options: RequestOptions;

    constructor(private http:Http)
    {

    }

    registerUser(details : any) : Promise<any>
    {               
        //alert(details);
        //this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 
          //                           'Accept': 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9' });
        //this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
        return this.http.post("http://localhost/Angular6http/UserDetails/src/app/data.php",details).toPromise().then(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {

        //alert(res);       
        let body = res.json();
        //alert(body);
        return body || {};      
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `alert(JSON.stringify(form.value))` to show data in alert

Comment: I don't want the data from form.value, getting that perfectly fine, what I want is to fetch data from this.data

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in your service.

```
return this.http.post("http://localhost/Angular6http/UserDetails/src/app/data.php",details)      
  .toPromise()
  .then(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

You are calling `extractData` and `handleError` functions without the `()`, which has nothing to do with the solution to your issue, it's just a point I'm raising. You also do not need to call those functions at all, since you want to return the promise.

The following code should work:

```
return this.http.post("http://localhost/Angular6http/UserDetails/src/app/data.php",details)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .toPromise();
```

You are already handling the `.then()` inside your component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    registerUser(form: NgForm)
{
    //console.log(form.value);      
    let details = JSON.stringify(form.value);                       
    this.listingService.registerUser(details)
    .then((result) => {console.log(result); this.userdata = result; this.data = result; alert(this.data);})
    .catch(error => console.log(error));


}
```

Use the following line in your service:

```
return this.http.post("http://localhost/Angular6http/UserDetails/src/app/data.php",details)
```

Comment: Then I tried using alert(this.data["_body"]) which gave me the entire array finally

Comment: I got something like : [{"Id":"1","Name":"Yamini Babani","Email":"yamini@gmail.com","Address":"gandhidham","Role":"User","Gender":"female"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Jitendra Ahuja","Email":"jitendraahuja273@gmail.com","Address":"Ahmedabad","Role":"Super-Admin","Gender":"male"},{"Id":"3","Name":"Yash Patel","Email":"yash@yahoo.com","Address":"Ahmedabad","Role":"Admin","Gender":"male"}], now what if I want to fetch all the data individually from {...data...}, one by one in template

Comment: Also We cannot return without adding .toPromise() from a service as it shows error when it reaches .then() in component.... bcoz for .then() , data must be in Promise form , which is done by .toPromise() method

Comment: Try .subscribe() instead of .then()

Comment: remove the return  Promise<any> from registerUser function

Comment: but isn't that the observable's method to get data, i purely need to use promises as of now

Comment: OK. Do what I have said and tell me the result.
The returned value form the registerUser function is Observable (Like Promise).

Comment: Why are you not responding ?
If you solved your problem accept the answer or tell me that it was not the correct answer.